# Run-time error '3075': Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[Order Number] = '

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

i have this error on a DLookup function, although there are alot of questions all over the web for this non of the solutions seem to solve my problems, either that or i'm not doing it right.

Here is the line of code causing me grief:

```
startID = DLookup("[Sandwich Order ID]", "Sandwich Orders", "[Order Number] = " & Me.Order_Number.Value)
```

Comment: what is Me.Order_Number.Value's value?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav It's an autonumber gotten from a field on a form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will happen on a new record or similar where order number is *Null*. And if no sandwich can be looked up, `DLookup` returns *Null*, thus:

```
startID = Nz(DLookup("[Sandwich Order ID]", "Sandwich Orders", "[Order Number] = " & Nz(Me!Order_Number.Value, 0)), 0)
```